# Using a hurricane electric tunnel to provide IPs to a network with dnsmasq

Tags: linux, networking, router, ipv6

I run my network off a x86 box running Ubuntu 18.04, firewalld (UFW is unsuitable for use as a router), /networks/interfaces (netplan had a bug that made it unfit for purpose) and dnsmasq for DHCP and DNS.

I had an ISP that ran ipv6 with PD and I used [the setup here](https://superuser.com/questions/742792/how-do-i-deploy-ipv6-within-a-lan-using-a-debian-based-router-and-prefix-delegat). My current ISP dosen't support IPV6 so I've gotten a tunnel set up to my router through hurricane electric - this is set up, and presumably works since I can ping .

I have enp1s0 as the external interface, and all other interfaces bridged together serving the rest of the network as br0. Also have he-ipv6 as the tunnel, not bridged to anything

At the moment the router is sitting behind an ISP router, with two different network segments - 192.168.1.x for everyone else, and my own test network in 192.168.2.x, with the router in a DMZ. This *shouldn't* be a problem.

The problem is I'd like to stick with dnsmasq, and I'm having trouble funding documentation on how to set it.

Here's what I have right now

- I've set up ipv6 to my router as per the instructions on hurricane electric's web page including the below on my /etc/networks/interfaces

```
auto he-ipv6
iface he-ipv6 inet6 v4tunnel
        address 2001:470:YY:YYYY::2
        netmask 64
        endpoint 216.218.221.6
        local xxx.xxx.x.xxx
        ttl 255
        gateway 2001:470:YY:YYYY::1
```

This works. I can ping ipv6.google.com and other known ipv6 sites. I just don't seem to be able to get IPs for *anything else*.

I tried

```
##For HE
enable-ra
dhcp-range = 2001:470:YY:YYYY::
dhcp-option=option6:dns-server,[2001:470:20::2],[2001:4860:4860::8888]
```

But apparently the syntax is wrong.

How do I get an IPv6 address for clients getting IPs from the router, as well as for br0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before everything else:

Just as in IPv4, each link needs its own subnet prefix. The `2001:470:YY:YYYY::/64` "tunnel endpoint" is specifically for the link between you and Hurricane (i.e. it's for your "WAN address" in IPv4 terms) – it cannot be reused for any of your LANs. For the latter you need one of the "Routed IPv6 prefixes" found in the tunnel settings page – this will be the equivalent of a DHCPv6-PD delegated prefix.

Normally each LAN has a /64-sized subnet prefix, to allow for standard-SLAAC-based address assignment to work (many clients, especially Android, do not support DHCPv6-based address assignment). So if you plan on multiple subnets, choose "Assign /48" to get a prefix with a decent amount (64ki) of /64's.

(You don't need to use "Assign /64" if you have already assigned a /48. If you *did* use "Assign /64", note that the prefix is *slightly* different from the "tunnel endpoints" prefix; they're often confused.)

---

Once you have your own range, say 2001:470:ZZ::/48, pick a /64 out of it (ranging from 0 to ffff, such as 2001:470:ZZ:**1**::/64) and use that for your `br0` interface as well as for dnsmasq configuration.

```
enable-ra
dhcp-range = 2001:470:ZZ:1::, ra-stateless
dhcp-option = option6:dns-server, [2001:470:20::2], [2001:4860:4860::8888]
```

As previously mentioned, many clients (notably Android) **do not support** address assignment via DHCPv6. They require SLAAC, so you need at least one of **`slaac`** or **`ra-stateless`** in the 'dhcp-range' config. (The mode 'ra-stateless' additionally tells SLAAC clients that they can still get DNS settings from DHCPv6, which is useful for Windows. Regardless of selection, dnsmasq will also automatically provide DNS servers via SLAAC-RDNSS for Android.)

However, for **br0** (or whatever the LAN interface is) you should assign an IP address statically – I'm not sure whether the kernel receives its own multicasts, nor whether it pays attention to them. In any case, I suspect *dnsmasq itself* might refuse to run on an interface that lacks a matching address (like it already does for IPv4)...

```
iface br0 inet6 static
    address 2001:470:ZZ:1::1/64

iface br1 inet6 static
    address 2001:470:ZZ:2::1/64
```

---

Once you have dnsmasq running, use `rdisc6 eth0` from another Linux system to solicit and show the contents of a Router Advertisement. Make sure it has a non-zero "Router lifetime"; at least one "Prefix" (which needs to be a /64, on-link, autonomous, non-zero valid time); and that it comes from a link-local `fe80::*` address and not from a global address.

Comment: I'll review the actual dnsmasq.conf syntax once I have returned to the computer that actually has a working configuration from earlier...

Comment: Annnd, it works. I only have a br1 - and having the /64 is probably the bit I missed.

Comment: actually something else seems broken. erf. I *do* get an IP, and I can ping google, but nothing else seems to work

Comment: Use tcpdump to see where things go (or don't go). Do a DNS query, make sure it arrives at br1 and exits at he-ipv6 and the response comes back. (e.g. if you see a large packet being re-sent over and over, consider lowering the advertised MTU and making sure you don't block ICMPv6.)

Comment: I worked out it was my firewall rules - I run firewalld but had to do the equivilent of `FORWARD 0 -i he-ipv6 -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT` and `FORWARD 0 -i br0 -o  he-ipv6 -j ACCEPT` amusingly, this happened the last time I set up ipv6 on this thing too and I had it documented ><