# How to configure DHCPv6 in Proxmox without bridge

Tags: dhcp, ipv6, proxmox, ndp

(crossposts: <del>[Network stack exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/77253/how-to-configure-dhcpv6-in-proxmox-without-bridge)</del>, [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1085864/how-to-configure-dhcpv6-in-proxmox-without-bridge))

I have a setup with Proxmox connected via Wi-Fi. Everything works for my needs and IPv4 connectivity too.

Now, I want to see if it is possible to do some DHCPv6 setup so that my virtual machines have IPv6 addresses as well. I'd prefer a setup without NAT, but it's not mandatory that it is so.

I'm taking a few options into consideration for IPv6 connectivity:

- NDP Proxy. This one feels like it's the most "transparent", and I will get a public IPv6 address from the same network as the host, which is the main abcd:abcd:abcd:FFFF::/64 network.
- DHCPv6 network. My router has DHCPv6, I can probably make my Proxmox instance request a network to use for its internal bridge (using prefix delegation). I'm currently using dnsmasq for the IPv4 addresses of virtual machines, but I believe I can replace it with something else.
- NAT. I don't want this option, but I also won't decline it completely
  either. The reason why I cannot just connect the Proxmox bridge in
  bridge mode to my LAN (which would have made things significantly
  easier) is the fact that I cannot bring in a wired connection, so I
  have to use Wi-Fi (thankfully at least it's 5 GHz and there's no need
  for much traffic most of the time) and Wi-Fi client doesn't support
  bridges.

So here is my request for advice. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Found answer in https://superuser.com/questions/742792/how-do-i-deploy-ipv6-within-a-lan-using-a-debian-based-router-and-prefix-delegat

Comment: @Toto It does, hence why I voted for closing (as duplicate). Thank you.